# Best practice for clear button in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

When adding a clear button to a UITextField, which option do you normally select for when the clear button appears (appears while editing, appears unless editing, always visible)? I want to choose the one that is unintrusive but useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I use "appear while editing" too. But it really depend of what is the purpose of the textfield.

For example:
- If you use the textfield for search like function, you may want to leave the clear button always visible, so if the use want to clear the text it's faster.
- If it's in a registration page, it's not really useful to have a clear button (you may press the x by mistake) because it's just one time competition.

(Sorry, my english is not the best :) )

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it to appear while editing.